# How to access attributes of a class instance which is a graph node via the graph?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, undirected-graph

Class definition:

```
class Blah:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
```

Part of main(): (imported networkx)

```
G = networkx.Graph()
H = []

for i in range(1,5):
    H.append(Blah(i))

for i in H:
    G.add_node(i)
```

Now, if I want to print `H[2].x` using G then how do I do it?

`G[2].x` certainly wouldn't work. Will `G(H[2]).x` work?

Just asking for information. I can use H in my problem.

Comment: I think you mean `for i in H: G.add_node(i)`?

Comment: @yatu Oh sorry, that was a typing mistake. Edited.

Comment: So what is it that you'r expecting?

Comment: Is it he node data?

Comment: @yatu I want to access x for a particular node of G but I don't know which element of H that particular node is. Is there a way to access x through G?

Comment: @yatu yes it is an attribute for H and instances of H become nodes of G.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to go through `G` to get `H[2].x` at all.

Comment: "I want to access x for a particular node of G but I don't know which element of H that particular node is." - then what *do* you know? Do you have the node?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I want to add edges between certain nodes based on a manipulation of the values of their corresponding x attribute.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes I have the nodes which are elements of the list H which in turn are instances of the class Blah. Now, I wish to add edges between certain nodes by computing a number using the values of x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you define:

```
class Blah:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

G = networkx.Graph()
H = []

for i in range(1,5):
    H.append(Blah(i))

for i in H:
    G.add_node(i)
```

Now you want to access the attributes of nodes of G.  To do that, you need to use the networkx commands to access the nodes of G:

```
for node in G:
    print(node.x)
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Joel. Is there a way to index nodes (like G[2])?

Answer (score 1):

you can access the node data as shown below

`print(list(G.nodes())[1].x)`